# Los resultados no se muestran en el iframe

Tags: javascript, formularios

Tengo este código y no se porqué los resultados no se muestran en el iframe. Apenas tengo conocimientos y lo que estoy leyendo por la web no me ayuda nada. Gracias.

```
<script>
function enviar(){
  dato1 = document.getElementById('dato1').value;
  dato2 = document.getElementById('dato2').value;
  document.getElementById("myform").target = "iframeUpload";
  document.myform.action = 
  "http://www.google.es/maps/search/"+dato1+"+"+dato2;
 document.myform.submit();
}
</script>
<form name="myform" action="" method="get">
<input type="text" value="" id="dato1" />
<input type="text" value="" id="dato2" />
<input type="button" value="enviar" onclick="enviar();" />
 </form>
 <iframe id="iframeUpload" name="iframeUpload"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

No te carga el resultado porque Google no permite hacerlo.

Deberías consultar la documentación de Google Maps para desarrolladores para ver cómo hacerlo. En realidad únicamente necesitas registrarte para obtener una clave personal para uso de la API e incluir esta clave en las urls.

Tanto esta clave como su uso son gratuitos siempre que no se usen en aplicaciones comerciales o se exceda de un número de peticiones.

Referencia:

[Google Maps Embed API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/guide?hl=es-419)

Comment: Muy bien.. revisaré la referencia que me indicas.. creía que si podia hacerlo pues si quito la linea    document.getElementById("myform").target = "iframeUpload";     el formulario funciona perfectamente pero en una ventana nueva.